# Ошибка 419 при запросе. Python requests post

Tags: python, requests, post

Пытаюсь загрузить файл на https://gekkk.co/neo/create-post post запросом, но выдаёт ошибку 419. Что только не пробовал.

```
import requests
s = requests.session()
cookies = cookies.cookies.get_dict()
print(cookies)

file_to_load = {'file.png':  open('source.png', 'rb')}
headers = {
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
'Accept-Language': 'ru,en;q=0.9',
'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
# 'Content-Length': '4224',
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryzL1JxGTaYLAM4tz3',
# 'Cookie': 'XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Il23fsa2vbVJhVm10OE9GQ0t6R1wvVUx3Pf2wqafJ2YWx1ZSI6IjI4bmRzZEMrQ25Zd1wvTFZEVit5UldqSkNiOXlSWW9rNmJ1T3c3bUUzSDIyTmpOa0pPU280Ukx4ZFJOT0M4RlpiIiwibWFjIjoiNTgzM2RjYTdjZjczNGQ0N2Q2NzYyYzUwZDE3ODUxZmYxZWM2ODc5OWFlNDMyM2EyNGM1YzgwMjFjNzE4ZGI4MyJ9; brainshare_session=eyJpdiI6ImhaVTZnYlNCTmFMNDI5N21VdjR0dFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYnBNaVNZRzRUdGdobk9lankyQW82akRRNWowWGhoa1drbStmYlpNaDU2aU1MbStJWnZyaUpSSE80cXVGWHg0KyIsIm1hYyI6IjYzNWIzYzgzNjExNGZlNTY0ZjAyZGY5ODIyMjdjNWZhMTEzMzIzZTY5NzJiZjJkNzdkOWZjMDEzOGRkZGZhY2IifQ%3D%3D',
'Origin': 'https://gekkk.co',
'Referer': 'https://gekkk.co/',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.5845.837 YaBrowser/23.9.4.837 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "YaBrowser";v="23"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',}


response = requests.post('https://gekkk.co/neo/create-post', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, files=file_to_load)
print(response.status_code)
```

Что только не пробовал. Получаю status_code 419.

Копировал запрос само собой через curl converter

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум ошибка в низу. Ты создал сессию а потом просто обычный запрос фигачишь.
`response = requests.post()` должно быть как минимум `response = s.post` где `s` твоя сессия.
А вообще базовый синтаксис.

```
session = requests.session()  #создаём сессию
url = "http://localhost"
session.get(url)   #получаем cookie
data = {"username": "", "password": ""} 
response = session.post(url, data=data) #логинимся
```

Comment: Я пробовал и сессией пост запрос. Ничего не меняется

Comment: Разкомментируй  строку X-CSRF-TOKEN. Попробуй так переписать. "XSRF-TOKEN":"ключ"